# Can I use a Promise as the default value of a function's parameter?

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to use the value of a Promise as the default parameter of a function like this:

```
_drawElement(selector, html = this._htmlFrom(selector)) {
  console.log(html);
}

_htmlFrom(templateName) {
  var templatePath = `${this._templates}/${templateName}.html`;
  return fetch(templatePath)
    .then((response) => response.ok ? response.text() : null)
}
```

But I'd like html to be a string 'cause I can pass it with other ways than the htmlFrom function. Here I have a promise and I don't know how to retrieve the string value (or null).

Okay so following the advice of CertainPerformance I did this:

```
async _drawElement(selector, html = this._htmlFrom(selector)) {
var tags = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
if (tags.length == 1) {
  console.log(html);
  var isPromise = typeof html.then == 'function';
  if (isPromise) {
    html = await html;
  }
...
}
```

but idk why, _htmlFrom function is called, even when I call the function with a value for html. (why is html a promise even when i give a string as parameter)

Comment: Wait for the promise to resolve inside `_drawElement`.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: So sometimes when you use `_drawElement`, you pass the `selector` as well as `html` which is a string?

Comment: Yes! Either I pass a string as html, or I pass nothing, then the htmlFrom is called and should return a string, but it returns a function.

Comment: Okay, did you try the answer which is already posted?

Comment: You shouldn't be passing a Promise to a function. Make it the caller's responsibility to use `await` or `.then()`, and call the function in the normal way, passing the value delivered by the promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML you need is retrieved asynchronously, and unfortunately there's no way to wait for it to complete *inside the parameter list*. You'll have to wait for it on the first line of the function instead:

```
async _drawElement(selector, html) {
  if (html === undefined) {
    html = await this._htmlFrom(selector);
  }
  console.log(html);
}
```

Comment: What if I do something like:

   async _drawElement(selector, html = this._htmlFrom(selector)) {
    var tags = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    if (tags.length == 1) {
      console.log(html);
      var isPromise = typeof html.then == 'function';
      if (isPromise) {
        html = await html;
      }

Comment: (sorry I don't know how to format my comment)
I'm editing my post.

Comment: That's quite verbose (more code is generally harder to read and means more surface area for bugs) why not just use the code in the answer?

Comment: @GaetanL. Drop the `isPromise` stuff, just do `html = await html`.